# How to create a calculated field with a where clause in the calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

[The image shows the table from this code:  select * from PunchClock
where punchmonth = 1 and PunchDay = 1 and PunchYear = 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsHZ2.png)

I am trying to calculate the number of hours worked per day in a database. Our table for this has 2 columns that pertain to this. InOut is a column that has either 1 or 0 (1 = punch in, 0 = punch out), and then there is the punchdatetime. How could I use these two fields to calculate how many hours are worked per day.

I have tried to subtract the punch time in from the punch time out but that won't work.

```
select PunchMonth, PunchDay, PunchYear, 
      ((PunchDateTime where InOut = 0) - (punchdatetime where InOut = 1))
  from PunchClock
```

Error Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: It looks like you have a table that has a record for the punch in, and a record from the punch out. This will require more than just a simple query from a single table. Sample data and results will definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

could be you need  case (not where)

```
select PunchMonth
  , PunchDay
  , PunchYear
  , case INOut = 0 then PunchDateTime else -PunchDateTime end
from PunchClock
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `case` expression.  Also, because a given row has either an `InOut` value of `0` or `1` but not both, I think you need aggregation.

So, I'm guessing:

```
select PunchMonth, PunchDay, PunchYear,
       datediff(second, min(case when InOut = 0 then punchdatetime end),
                max(case when InOut = 1 then punchdatetime  end)
               ) as seconds_diff
from PunchClock
group by PunchMonth, PunchDay, PunchYear;
```